# Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/mytheme/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1025

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, meta-boxes

Im trying to add variables instead of custom field IDs in my metaboxes file using [this script](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes)

I added some options in redux framework to give possibility to change the custom fields.

```
<?php
/*global from framework*/
global $redux;
/*custom fields options retrieved from redux framework*/
$custom_videourl = $redux['mytheme_videourl'];
$custom_duration = $redux['mytheme_duration'];
$custom_description = $redux['mytheme_desc'];
$fields = array(
    array(
     'label' => __( 'MP4/FLV & Youtube Url', 'framework' ),
     'desc' => __( 'Here you can add videos with mp4 format', 'framework' ),
     'id' => $custom_videourl,
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    array(
     'label' => __( 'Video Duration', 'framework' ),
     'desc' => __( 'Example: 5:20', 'framework' ),
     'id' => $custom_duration,
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    array(
     'label' => __( 'Video Description', 'framework' ),
     'id' => $custom_description,
     'desc' => __( 'Here you can write a description', 'framework' ),
     'type' => 'editor'
    )
);
$my_metaboxes = new custom_add_meta_box( 'mytheme_metaboxes', __( 'Video - Additional Information', 'framework' ), $fields, 'post', true );
```

But with the above example I got  **Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/mytheme/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1025**

So if I add the custom field without variable metaboxes are working fine like below content:

```
$fields = array(
    array(
     'label' => __( 'MP4/FLV & Youtube Url', 'framework' ),
     'desc' => __( 'Here you can add videos with mp4 format', 'framework' ),
     'id' => 'mytheme_videourl',
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    array(
     'label' => __( 'Video Duration', 'framework' ),
     'desc' => __( 'Example: 5:20', 'framework' ),
     'id' => 'mytheme_duration',
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    array(
     'label' => __( 'Video Description', 'framework' ),
     'id' => 'mytheme_desc',
     'desc' => __( 'Here you can write a description', 'framework' ),
     'type' => 'editor'
    )
);
$my_metaboxes = new custom_add_meta_box( 'mytheme_metaboxes', __( 'Video - Additional Information', 'framework' ), $fields, 'post', true );
```

I have tried using print_r but metaboxes don't save than. Is there any way to make the first code working? Using variables instead of custom field IDs?

Comment: What is the content of eg. `$redux['mytheme_videourl'];` ? The Notice says that it is an array, but you just want to have a particular element.

Comment: `$redux['mytheme_videourl'];` is a redux framework option its just a field in my redux / theme settings panel.I want to give the possibility to make the customfields changable as you see Im calling global $redux from database but I want just to use these variables in my metaboxes file.Metaboxes file is creating the custom field options below post editor and the notice is below post editor too.

Comment: Yeah I know, but `$redux['mytheme_videourl'];` is an array, not a String. Can you do a `print_r($redux['mytheme_videourl'])` somewhere, where you can see its contents? Or `print_r($redux['mytheme_videourl'], true)` as description or similar, so that you can see its content?

Comment: Yes I have tried with print_r but the custom field value disappears when i do that.

Comment: Im gonna make a new try

Comment: You can also print it to the WordPress Logfile and look it up there: Set `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` and then you can do a `error_log(print_r($redux['mytheme_videourl'], true));`. After that, you can look at the logfile which you can find in `/wp-content/debug.log`

Comment: I tried with print which is worked and saved the custom field.But in redux option I changed the custom field name to test so its called test but after saving the post with the description metabox it saved it but renamed the custom field to 1 instead of retrieving from redux panel :( so when I checked the custom fields section in post editor the custom field is called just 1 instead of test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142053/discussion-between-eknoes-and-gazi).

Answer (score 4):

It seems really likely that one of your redux variables contains an Array instead of a String.  Knowing that, you just need to figure out which one it is and figure out where the actual piece of data that you are looking for is.

One way you could debug this is to do an explicit conversion of all three of the redux variables to strings.  (e.g. `'id' => implode("***", $custom_videourl)`).  Then, once you've figured out which one (or more than one) is an array, you'll probably know how to access the piece of data you actually want.

If that doesn't do it for you, I would suggest adding this to your wp-config.php file: `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true )`;

This will create a debug log for you.  You can then log out to it (e.g. `error_log( print_r( $custom_videourl )` ); 
I believe it usually stores the debug.log file in the wp-content folder.

Comment: Let me explain you better, the codes in my question are using this one https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box and Im calling redux variables in this metaboxes script but the redux variables are just text fields in redux framework

Comment: The redux variable is working fine when  I remove from brainternet script (like on my second code) and call it with get post meta command `get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_videourl, true);` the problem is only in the metaboxes fields. Im allways working with debug on however Im gonna take a look with your explantion using the implode

Comment: @Gazi How did it work out?  I'm interested in knowing where the error came from.

Comment: I resolved with another method because its not possible to use like in my question I have just used my second code and created to custom field one from redux and one from metabox I dont know how to explain but it was not possible to have an answer for my question since its impossible

Comment: I'm sorry to belabor this, but I am doing so in case someone else has a similar problem.  Are you saying that you were not able to tell whether one of your variables unexpectedly had an array in it or not?

Comment: I have used the second metabox code which I have in my question and I did something like this in my outputs file `$video_custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, $redux['videourl'], true);
$video_default = get_post_meta($post->ID,'mytheme_videourl', true);` than I equated two custom fields with this one: `if($video_custom == "" && $video_default != "") { $video_custom = $video_default; }` so the final is here: `if (!empty($video_custom)) { echo $video_custom; }` both custom fields works here.The user can change custom field in redux framework settings without any problem.

Comment: It was no possible for me to add $variables in the metaboxes file as ID, since I couldnt find a solution there I found my way using above results.

Comment: I get that you're focussed on solving your overall issue (how to make your metabox code work), but that is not what you asked in your question.  You asked why you got the error message you got.  I answered that.  Future SO users will come to this question when they have a similar question and you should indicate whether my answer solved the part of your question that is described in your question title and in the code you posted.

Comment: yes because in my question I couldnt find any correct answer or comment since its not resolved I have used this one.Sure that would be better resolving my question instead but I dont have any idea how to do it and no one posted a solution